# Sort numeric in php

Tags: php

this sorts array :

```
sort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

this sorts 1.jpg, 2.jpg ...
But what about 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 2-1.jpg, 2-2.jpg. Above function not sorts this type. How can I do this with sorts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Take a lot at natsort https://www.php.net/natsort

If this isn't able to handle what you need, the usort() function and a custom functin of your own can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove SORT_NUMERIC argument.